# Is it possible to force Node.js / Electron app to use high-performance (discrete) GPU programmatically?

Tags: node.js, electron, operating-system, gpu, chromium

I have an Electron app and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to **programmatically** force OS to run it on high-performance (discrete) GPU instead of the integrated GPU.

Is there a CLI command / hack that can force OS to do this (similarly to how games automatically run on discrete GPU)?

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39047129/12125881), but I'm not sure how to apply it for Node.js:

```
// Enable dedicated graphics for NVIDIA:

extern "C" 
{
  __declspec(dllexport) unsigned long NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
}

// Enable dedicated graphics for AMD Radeon:

extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [gpu.js](https://blog.bitsrc.io/using-gpu-to-improve-javascript-performance-e5a41c2e129b)? The linked blog post offers useful examples.

Edit:
Ah, entire app. How about the Electron flag [--force_high_performance_gpu](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/command-line-switches)?

If that doesn't work someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464276/how-to-force-discrete-gpu-in-electron-js) figured out a way to restart the app on dGPU. ...although the thread also mentions it's on dedicated by default, so maybe something changed in the last couple years?

Comment: This library is for running code on GPU, not the app  itself